# Problema con Watchposition y setInterval HTML5

Tags: javascript, html5, geolocalización

Tengo el siguiente codigo con el cual puedo obtener las coordenadas de un telefono cada 15 segundos.

El problema es que si el telefono se bloquea, la funcion setInterval deja de funcionar y ya no me guarda las coordenadas hasta despues de desbloquear el telefono.

```
function setGeolocation() {
var geolocation = window.navigator.geolocation.watchPosition( 
    function ( position ) {
        var location=new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude)
  coordenadasRuta.push(location);
    },
    function () { /*error*/ }, {
        maximumAge: 250, 
        enableHighAccuracy: true
    } 
);

window.setTimeout( function () {
        window.navigator.geolocation.clearWatch( geolocation ) 
    }, 
    5000
   );
}; 

setGeolocation();
window.setInterval( function () { 
    setGeolocation();
}, 15000);
```

Esas coordenadas luego las guardo para crear una PolyLine por lo que si se bloquea no me guarda la ruta correctamente.

Tenes alguna Idea de porque pasa esto?

Answer (score 0):

el problema es que el sistema android del movil te esta apagando el proceso para ahorrar bateria de forma predeterminada como presupongo que accedes desde un navegador no se me acude como obligar a mantenerlo en memoria, sino hay diversos post con informacion de como mantener aplicaciones android en background y optimizar memoria

Answer (score 0):

Utilza `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showLocation, errorHandler, options)`

Donde `options` es un objeto que le puedes pasar el `timeout`.

Ejemplo:

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showLocation, errorHandler, options)

var options = {
        timeout: 1000
    };

function errorHandler(err) {
        if (err.code == 1) {
            $("#status").append("Error: Access is denied!<br>");
        } else if (err.code == 2) {
            $("#status").append("Error: Position is unavailable!<br>");
        }
    }
function showLocation(position) {
        console.log(position);
        var d = new Date();
        $("#status").append(d + "--> " + position.coords.longitude + " - " + position.coords.latitude + " -- " + position.coords.speed + "<br>");
    }
```